# Portfolio Optimization using r and solve.QP

Tags: r, optimization, finance, portfolio

I'm trying to solve a quadratic programming problem for my portfolio optimization class using r.  I would like to compare my answer to one in a book.
Here is the problem:
    `min: t(c)%*%x + .5*t(x)%*%BigC%*%x

    st: -x <=0, i=1...5

    and: sum(x)=1`

Here is my code:

```
A = matrix( c( 1,1,1,1,1, -1,0,0,0,0, 0,-1,0,0,0, 0,0,-1,0,0, 0,0,0,-1,0, 0,0,0,0,-1), ncol=5, byrow=T)
b = matrix( c( 1,0,0,0,0,0), ncol=1)
c = matrix( c( 1,-2,3,-4,5), ncol=1)
BigC = matrix( c( 1,0,0,0,0,  0,2,0,0,0,  0,0,3,0,0,  0,0,0,4,0,  0,0,0,0,5), ncol=5, byrow=T)
x0 = matrix( c( 0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2), ncol=1)
n = 5
m = 5
q = 1
solve.QP( Dmat=BigC, dvec=t(c), Amat=t(A), bvec=t(b), meq=1)
```

but it throws the following error:

```
Error in solve.QP(Dmat = BigC, dvec = t(c), Amat = t(A), bvec = t(b),  : 
  constraints are inconsistent, no solution!
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: So what's the problem with that code? What's your question?

Answer (score 3):

The `?solve.QP` doc mentions

> problems of the form min(-d^T b + 1/2 b^T D b) with the constraints A^T b >= b_0.

so you have at least two things wrong:

- the signs within `A` for expressing your `x_i >= 0` constraints
- `dvec` should be `-t(c)`

Let's also mention that

- in the future, it's important you mention that you are using the `quadprog` package,
- `solve.QP` takes vectors so you don't need to create matrices and transpose them,
- you should avoid naming variables `c` since it is the name of a common function in R,
- some of your code was not used, hence irrelevant to the question,
- the convenient `diag` function.

Taking all this into account, this is what you are looking for:

```
library(quadprog)

A    <- rbind(rep(1, 5), diag(5))
b    <- c( 1,0,0,0,0,0)
tc   <- c( 1,-2,3,-4,5)
BigC <- diag(1:5)

solve.QP(Dmat = BigC, dvec = -tc, Amat = t(A), bvec = b, meq = 1)
```

Comment: @JasonBeach, glad to help and welcome to SO. I'm sorry your question was downvoted so much, I hope it won't stop you from asking next time. If you think I answered your question, please consider accepting it as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask